# Samsung SSD firmware update fails

Tags: windows-7, ssd, firmware

Samsung Magician checks for new firmware update, finds it, prompts me to install it, I let it do that, then it fails to update. The SSD is an 840 EVO, 250 GB. I'll let the screenshots tell the story.

[image: a]

[image: b]

[image: c]

[image: d]

[image: e]

[image: f]

Error message:

> Failed to update firmware on the selected drive.

**Why is this happening, and what can I do about it if I want to update the firmware?**

Comment: Some report this as being [AHCI and/or AMD related](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-1853857/samsung-840-evo-firmware-update-ext0bb0q.html). I do have an AMD chipset, and AHCI is enabled last time I checked.

Comment: I'd suggest just burning the firmware update ISO to a CD or DVD and booting from it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Will this in fact erase everything on the SSD?

Comment: No. It will have no effect on the data on the SSD. Though it's a good idea to make a backup before a firmware upgrade just in case. (Regardless of how you do it.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I notice the firmware "EXT0BB0Q" which is already on the SSD is not listed on [Samsung website](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/samsungssd/downloads.html)? But the "EXT0BB6Q" is listed as a EVO 840 firmware. I just want to make sure I get the correct one.